# WooCommerce: cannot remove the price from a single product page through functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is odd as the price still displays with this code:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

I can remove the title with this code:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Anything I should look for?

Answer (score 4):

WordPress is the best cms and Woocommerce is the best E-commerce plugin. WordPress hooks(add_action, add_filter) give us the power to edit or change the code without interruption into the files and this is the best thing about WordPress.

Add this in function.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can remove price from single product page :

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customizing_single_product_summary_hooks', 2  );
function customizing_single_product_summary_hooks(){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_price',10  );

}
```

Add above code in your active theme's function.php.

Tested and it works perfect.

Comment: No joy with this. I am thinking there may be a problem with the purchased theme.

Answer (score 0):

It is only priority. Just remove from the larger one and adding to the lower one. like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 7 );
```

Here, I have removed pricing from the higher priority and adding to the lower priority, you don't need to remove title as you want price below the title so title have `5` priority and price have `7`. So it will work.

Please try this way.

Comment: This does not remove the price but adds a second above the SKU (meta). This is what I wish to achieve but it will not remove the price below the meta with priority 10.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the priority issue with the action hook. Please check by using the following code. Hope it helps.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide it with CSS, but if you want to remove it completely from the page's html result, try

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price ) {
return ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the actual aim here is to move it below the title. So I need to add_action back in and change the priority, but this gives me 2 prices.

Comment: The topic only mentioned removing the price from the single product page. If it's a purchased theme, did you reach out or opened a ticket on the vendor's website?