# How do I remove the price and price range from a single product page but allow it to show on /product-category pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

First thing first, thanks for looking at this and I appreciate your time. I have some experience in this but not a lot, but I have been looking for answers online with no luck.

I am working on a WooCommerce store and I am using the Ultimate Products Add-Ons plugin which displays a total price just above the "Add to Cart" button that will show all optional product add-ons giving a total price (before taxes). So with this being the only way to show a price before adding it to the cart, I need to remove a couple of things off of the Single Product Page, those being the price range and the standard price that typically shows on a single product page. I need to do this without removing the price from the Shop or /product-category pages. I played around with some of the settings in Theme Options > WooCommerce and I can get them removed from the Single Product page but it also removes it from the /product-category pages too.

Looking into this, it appears that the price range is the bit of info that shows up on both the /product-category page and single product page, so I need to find a way to target the single product page specifically. I have found the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'lw_hide_variation_price', 10, 2);
function lw_hide_variation_price( $v_price, $v_product ) {
$v_product_types = array( 'variable');
if ( in_array ( $v_product->product_type, $v_product_types ) && !(is_shop()) ) {
return '';
}
// return regular price
return $v_price;
}
```

This will remove the product range from the single product page and the /product-category page. I don't quite understand what I am looking at, but I have messed around with it and didn't really help.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve what I am looking to do? Thanks in advance!!!

[Current appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zobu8.png) |
[End Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYX4f.png)

EDIT: I tried to use the code found on [WooCommerce: cannot remove the price from a single product page through functions.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045536/woocommerce-cannot-remove-the-price-from-a-single-product-page-through-function) and it did help in removing the top price point that was immediately below the product name, although I am still looking to remove the middle price point that remains (see picture).

Code Used on above page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customizing_single_product_summary_hooks', 2  );
function customizing_single_product_summary_hooks(){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_price',10  );

}
```

So for now I am looking for either a single section of code to replace what I referenced above OR a second line of code that would allow me to just remove the price on the single product page only.

Comment: It did not completely solve my issues, the pictures were taken after using the code, so the price that changes as I change the dropdown is still something I need to be removed.

Comment: The top section of the code removes the price from all pages, and I think that is expected. The second section does not appear to have any visible difference. I believe `return $price;` is the line that seems to be causing it not to work at all, but I am 1) not sure and 2) not sure how I would figure out how to make that work :(.